# Can I chain ::first-line and ::selection in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to place:: selection colors only in the first-line for my course homework. I am learning css3 now and
I was curious if I was able to do this. After searching the google, I found that I am not able to do it only in CSS, but I want to make sure ;)

```
p::first-line {
    color: red;
}

p::selection {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it seems, from my reading of the spec, that this isn't possible, as:

> Pseudo-classes are allowed anywhere in selectors while **pseudo-elements may only appear as the last segment of a selector**.<sup>1</sup>

<sub>**Emphasis** mine.</sub>

As both `::selection` and `::first-line` are pseudo-elements (as denoted by the double-colon) they cannot be combined within a selector as they would both need to be the last component of that selector.

Footnotes:

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-CSS2-971104/selector.html#h-6.7

Comment: Ok, you satisfied my curiosity. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped (in some way, even if only stop you chasing rainbows) :)